# Android: Facebook image sharing problem on Friends Wall

Tags: facebook

I am having problem in sharing the images on friends wall by facebook api. the error is as follows.

"message": "(#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user."

my code is

```
String graphPath = null;
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", shortMsg.getText().toString());
TextView friendID = (TextView)   shareToFriendDlg.findViewById(R.id.friendID_hiden_TextView);                       
params.putString("type", "photo");
params.putString("link",info.LINK);
params.putString("name",info.NAME);
params.putString("picture",info.PICTURE);
params.putString("caption",info.CAPTION);
params.putString("message", shortMsg.getText().toString());
params.putString("description", info.DESCRIPTION);
graphPath = friendID.getText().toString() + "/links";
    mAsyncRunner.request(graphPath, params, "POST", new AsyncRequestListener() {

                @Override
                    public void onComplete(JSONObject obj, Object state) {
                     Log.d("Sharing ", obj.toString());
                    Global.ApplicationActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                shareToFriendDlg.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(Global.ApplicationActivity, "Shared :-)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }
                                            });

                                                }
                                                    }, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message explains itself, You need to have a valid session with facebook to run this, first execute and create a valid facebook object with a valid sequence of permissions after having all these set up you can then proceed with image sharing implementation.

Comment: but i have already created a facebook session and i get a access token to pass it but still having the same issue.if any idea please help.

Comment: try clearing your current perms and accepting them again, sometimes you get the perms locked to the basics. This might be your issue, good luck.